# Trying to compare a list element

Tags: python, list

In the code below, at `if path_parts[-2:-1]=='training'` I want my function to step into counting files at that location. My `print(path_parts[-2:-1])` demonstrates that the code is finding the 'training' folder I'm looking for but the evaluation doesn't prove 'true'.

What am I doing wrong?

```
for dirs_name, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
    count=0
    name=''
    if os.path.basename(dirs_name)== '2016':
        path_parts = [x.lower() for x in dirs_name.split('\\')]
        print(path_parts[-2:-1])
        if path_parts[-2:-1] == 'training':
            'statement'

Output of the print statement       
['training']
['training']
['training']
['training']
```

Comment: What is `path_parts[-2:-1]` supposed to achieve? You realize that it's a list and you try to compare it with a string?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from your output, `path_parts[-2:-1]` is `['training']`. That's a list. But you're comparing it to `'training'`, which is a string.

You mean:

```
# Is this sublist equal to a list containing the string 'training'?
if path_parts[-2:-1] == ['training']:
```

or more simply:

```
# Is the element at position -2 equal to the string 'training'?
if path_parts[-2] == 'training':
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `path_parts[-2:-1]` returns a list (because you slice the list) and you then compare it with a string `'training'`. That's always `False` because these lists and strings are incomparable.

But you can simply access the second-last item with `path_parts[-2]`:

```
if path_parts[-2] == 'training':
```